# How to download rich text from server?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, database, richtext

Is there any way to download rich text and have it retain it's text format as a pdf, doc, etc without having any of it's html tags still present by using Javascript? I am currently trying to built a text editor with AngularJS and I was wondering if it will be possible for people to download what they edit online to their computers locally without having the format of the text they typed in altered.

Comment: See [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Why rich text? I guess they can also download and open simple HTML. By the way, did my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624450/execcommand-is-not-working-with-angularjs/42624814 help you out?