# ng-model not getting update with document.execCommand()

Tags: angularjs

I have two contenteditable having same ng-model when I cut or copy or paste any selection using keyboard shortcut both contenteditable get updated but if I use `document.execCommand()` ng-model not get updated, it only work for active contenteditable.

```
<div ng-model="test" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div ng-model="test" contenteditable="true"></div>


$scope.cutSelection= function(){ 
    document.execCommand("cut");

} //only work for active contenteditable
```

I am not getting any error it just not updating inactive contenteditable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.execCommand doesn't work in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781241/document-execcommand-doesnt-work-in-angularjs)

Comment: I am not getting any error, it just not updating ng-model.

Comment: Then maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624450/execcommand-is-not-working-with-angularjs